# Grammar: 'We are getting a divorce' or 'We are getting divorced'?

Tags: grammar

I more often than not, I hear people say - He / she / they are 'getting a divorce'. This does not sound correct to me. To my mind it implies, they're away to the shop to buy something, ie: 'they are getting a loaf of bread'. Surely it should be 'they are getting divorced' or 'they got divorced'? It's keeping me awake at night.

Comment: Please search before posting questions. [Here’s just one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/225976/can-we-say-he-divorced-instead-of-he-got-divorced) of the several recent posts about these expressions.

Comment: [Both your versions are in common use.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=We%27re+getting+a+divorce%2CWe%27re+getting+divorced&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) OR there's *We're **divorcing***. Or *He's divorcing me* or *I'm divorcing her*. Syntactically, they're all fine. Use whichever you like best.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how who seems like a native speaker asks a question like this. **get here is obtain** but get a loaf of bread is obtain or buy. *get* has many uses in English and is not just buy.

Answer (score 3):

*Get* is one of the words most richly endowed with multiple meanings in the English language. If “I’m **getting a headache**” doesn’t conjure for you images of heading to the store to purchase some pain, then *getting a divorce* may be seen as no different.

Consider “I’m **getting the idea** you don’t like her.” That’s perfectly idiomatic, and there’s no financial transaction involved here either. Nor is there cause to reword it to something like “I’m coming to subscribe to the idea that you don’t like her.”

Or even more closely parallel to your *getting a divorce*/*getting divorced*, consider “They’re **getting a reprimand** for their behavior” vice *getting reprimanded*.

Answer (score 1):

"Getting a divorce" is correct, since you are using a noun. You can use "get" in different ways than buying something or having something physically. "I'm getting a new couch" and "I'm getting a punch in the face" both use "get" however it's used differently.

"We are divorcing" is also correct, here you're using the verb. Both are very common and I can't think of a situation in which you have to choose between one or the other, so it's free to choose which phrasing you'd like to use.

Comment: _Getting divorced_ is perfectly idiomatic too (compare _getting married_). The court is going to perform the procedure of divorcing them.